# How to use special chars in admindocs?

Tags: django, django-admin-tools

I have comments to models with some special chars, for examle:

```
[...] informacją [...]
```

but when I run admin I get:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f0e3b35aa50> (<class 'django.utils.functional.__proxy__'>)
```

I have:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

at beginig of file. This was happen when I install django-admin-tools

Comment: Please paste full traceback

Answer (score 0):

try to use unicode function:

`output = unicode(stringWithSpecialChars)`